# How to adjust font size or kerning to fit line width?

Tags: fonts, line-breaking, microtype, font-expansion

I have some text that nearly fits the given line width. I can see that a minimal adjustment of font size or kerning would make the text fit, but how do I tell LaTeX to squeeze the text? Yes, this would be bad typography for an average paragraph, but in my case it is a custom In a custom quotation environment, that has a smaller font size anyway, so it won't look ugly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you compile your document with pdfLaTeX, use the [microtype](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/microtype.html) package and its font expansion feature. Microtype will try to horizontally stretch your font (by default from -2% to +2%), and this will affect line breaks (and in your case, possibly make the text fit).

Comment: Exactly. But in your case do it locally by defining a context by including something like `\SetExpansion[context = sloppy,shrink = 60,...]{encoding = {OT1,T1,TS1} }{}` in your preamble. Then you can write something like `{\microtypecontext{expansion=sloppy}This line is a smidgen too long...}` to kick in the local 'sloppy' context adjustment on just the enclosed text.

Comment: Thanks! The \SetExpansion and \microtypecontext solution did not work form me (I got "pdfTeX error (font expansion): using fonts with different limit of expansion in one paragraph is not allowed."), but \SetTracking solved the issue. I'll play around with more microtype options if needed.

Answer (score 2):

One *simple* thing that one could try is to increase the stretchability of the space between words, i.e.:

```
\setbox0\hbox{i} \spaceskip=\wd0 plus .15em minus .15em
```

And to keep it inside scope.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the last few words inside an `\mbox{...}` to discourage breaking the line.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: While this will work, it will still be (possibly very visible) longer than the other lines and cause an `overfull hbox` warning.

Comment: `\mbox{}` is used to mark a word not to be hyphenated. `\sloppy` could perhaps help here, better is to use package `microtype`.